# How do I use object-fit with a 16:9 image?

Tags: css, image-scaling, object-fit

I'm trying to figure out how to use `object-fit` to properly scale a 16:9 vertical image.

I've tried almost anything with no luck!

https://jsfiddle.net/pdocys3j/

```css
.container {
  width: 300px; /*any size*/
  height: 200px; /*any size*/
}

.object-fit-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /*magic*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="object-fit-cover" src="https://jardim-plant-images-development.s3.amazonaws.com/hfj1h9jq2q8o8tyv1r6dxhi4zrmn">
</div>
```

The expected result (without using `object-fit`:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px; /*any size*/
  height: 200px; /*any size*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.object-fit-cover {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="object-fit-cover" src="https://jardim-plant-images-development.s3.amazonaws.com/hfj1h9jq2q8o8tyv1r6dxhi4zrmn">
</div>
```

I am hoping that I could use `object-fit` instead. Thoughts on this approach?

Comment: why do you need that ratio? i'm asking to understand the context

Comment: you want the image large as the div? (100%)

Comment: @Berto99 Yeah I want it to scale to the full width and keep its height without warping.

Comment: try contain instead of cover

Comment: @TemaniAfif No dice. I got a similar result with: https://jsfiddle.net/6L1opqds/

Comment: I don't see you using contain instead of cover in that jsfiddle

Comment: Yeah - I already tried contain and it resizes it to fit the container but doesn't take up the full width/height.

Answer (score -1):

You can write:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.object-fit-cover {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="object-fit-cover" src="https://jardim-plant-images-development.s3.amazonaws.com/hfj1h9jq2q8o8tyv1r6dxhi4zrmn">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I'd like to keep the container a 200x200 or 300x300 box. I thought object-fit would keep the aspect ratio if I set it to cover.

Comment: @alvincrespo So you think that `object fit: cover` respects the aspect ratio of the image? That assumption is incorrect. It does NOT, and instead tries to fit the image in a new aspect ratio (in your case the aspect ratio defined by its parent).

Answer (score -1):

Just add `position: relative` to the container. This instructs its children that their width and height is relative to the width and height of this container (in this case 200 x 200 px).

```css
.container {
  width: 200px; /*any size*/
  height: 200px; /*any size*/
  position: relative;
}

.object-fit-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /*magic*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img 
    class="object-fit-cover" 
    src="https://jardim-plant-images-development.s3.amazonaws.com/hfj1h9jq2q8o8tyv1r6dxhi4zrmn">
</div>
```

If you want it to be responsive, you should add an extra container:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px; /*any size*/
}

.innercontainer {
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* 1:1 ratio */
  position: relative;
}

.object-fit-cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /*magic*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="innercontainer">
  <img 
    class="object-fit-cover" 
    src="https://jardim-plant-images-development.s3.amazonaws.com/hfj1h9jq2q8o8tyv1r6dxhi4zrmn">
 </div>
</div>
```